# The class does not get removed with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```js
var pageLayout = document.getElementById("page-layout");
var contactPage = document.getElementById("contact-page");
var aboutPage = document.getElementById("about-page");
var home = document.getElementById("Home");

homepages = [contactPage, aboutPage, home];

home.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0, j = homepages.length - 1; i < j; i++) {
    if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
      homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");

    }
  }
  home.classList.add("current-page");


}
aboutPage.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0, j = homepages.length - 1; i < j; i++) {
    if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
      homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");

    }
  }
  aboutPage.classList.add("current-page");

}
contactPage.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0, j = homepages.length - 1; i < j; i++) {
    if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
      homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");

    }
  }
  contactPage.classList.add("current-page");

}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="current-page" id="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="about-page">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="contact-page">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

It looks like when I use this code something gets wrong in the deletion of the class from the previous element since this is the result I am getting when going from one to another, the first one does not get the class removed:

[image]

Comment: You may want to add your CSS to the snippet I've added to your question to better illustrate the issue. Click the [edit] link, the click the "edit the above snippet" link after the snippet to edit the snippet. There is a box labeled "CSS" where you can add some CSS, at lease for `.current-page`, so that the change is obvious. I'm guessing it's because of the navigation that occurs when you click the links, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Your loop should be `i = 0; i < homepages.length; i++`. If you want to micro-optimise the reference to `homepages.length` then it would be `i = 0, j = homepages.length; i<j; i++`. OR just do `homepages.forEach(...)`

Comment: I think the whole code needs to be changed you can handle it in less and more effective statements

Comment: You ended up going down the path of lots of code duplication that the answer provided in your last question would have avoided. Copy pasting blocks of code so you can just make a minor change in each block is not a scalable programming approach

Answer (score 0):

That behavior was caused by this loop:

```
for (var i = 0, j = homepages.length - 1; i < j; i++)
```

At the `i < j` and you iterate by `homepages[i]`. It means that the loop **will not reach** the last element of the array homepages, which it's 'home' in your cases. Thus, you should change it to:

```
for (var i = 0, j = homepages.length; i < j; i++)
```

or make it even shorter:

```
for (var i = 0; i < homepages.length; i++)
```

Therefore the full code would be:

```js
var pageLayout = document.getElementById("page-layout");
var contactPage = document.getElementById("contact-page");
var aboutPage = document.getElementById("about-page");
var home = document.getElementById("Home");

homepages = [contactPage, aboutPage, home];

home.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < homepages.length; i++) {
    if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
      homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");

    }
  }
  home.classList.add("current-page");


}
aboutPage.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < homepages.length; i++) {
    if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
      homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");

    }
  }
  aboutPage.classList.add("current-page");

}
contactPage.onclick = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < homepages.length; i++) {
    if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
      homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");

    }
  }
  contactPage.classList.add("current-page");

}
```

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

.current-page {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="current-page" id="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="about-page">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="contact-page">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**BONUS**: You can make it even more simple by creating a function and relocate some lines.

```js
function currentPageIndicator(element) {
  var pageLayout = document.getElementById("page-layout");
  var contactPage = document.getElementById("contact-page");
  var aboutPage = document.getElementById("about-page");
  var home = document.getElementById("Home");

  const homepages = [contactPage, aboutPage, home];
  
  var elem = document.getElementById(element);
  for (var i = 0; i < homepages.length; i++) {
    if (homepages[i].classList.contains("current-page")) {
      homepages[i].classList.remove("current-page");
    }
  }
  elem.classList.add("current-page");
}
```

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

.current-page {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="list-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="current-page" id="Home" onclick="currentPageIndicator('Home')">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="about-page" onclick="currentPageIndicator('about-page')">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="contact-page" onclick="currentPageIndicator('contact-page')">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

- the code have a lot of unnecessary steps you can do that in more simple steps

1. add class for your html elements instead of creating id for everyone
2. loop through the elements and add one event for all of them
3. find the element have `current-page` class and remove it without loop
4. add class for clicked element

> HTML

```
 <nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#home" class="current-page items" id="Home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about" class="items">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact" class="items">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

> CSS

```
.current-page {
   color: #4CAF50;
}
```

> JS

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".items")
items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var currentPage = document.querySelector("a.current-page");
    if (currentPage) {
      currentPage.classList.remove("current-page")
    }
    if(this.href.indexOf("#home") > -1) {
      console.log("home clicked");
    } else if(this.href.indexOf("#about") > -1) {
      console.log("about clicked");
    } else if(this.href.indexOf("#contact") > -1) {
      console.log("contact clicked");
    }
    this.classList.add("current-page");
  });
})
```

Comment: it is indeed a very nice approach but the reason i did use the block that is for each element separately is because i wanted also to use javascript to change the body layout on click of each of these elements without reloading the page, and now i could just add a line of code pageLayout.innerHTML = "<p>this is the contact page</p>" where instead of the paragraph i would have the actuall body contents i would change. I yet do not know the better approach for vanilla js layout change instead

Comment: I think Reactjs can provide a better help for you if want you to make a web apps but for now i will suggest to create elements for each section like `<div id="contact">__here's your contact elements__</div>`, `<div id="home">elements</div>`  and hide them with `display: none` then when for example contact is clicked you can show it and hide the home element and when home click hide contact and show home  if you want an example edit your question for what you want to did and then i will update my answer to provide examples for you

Comment: The result will be something near of that https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/howto_js_hover_tabs.asp but when clicking the element

Comment: I'm edited `href` attribute, added some conditions to help you do something else when they are clicked